# Executing a script upon g8 project initialization

Tags: sbt, giter8

Suppose I'm doing locally:

```
g8 file://hello-world.g8/ --name=helloworld
```

and the structure of `hello-world.g8` is:

```scala
├── build.sbt
├── LICENSE.md
├── project
│  ├── build.properties
│  ├── giter8.sbt
├── README.md
└── src
   └── main
      └── g8
         ├── build.sbt
         ├── default.properties
         ├── project
         │  ├── build.properties
         │  └── plugins.sbt
         └── src
            ├── main
            │  └── scala
            └── test
               └── scala
```

Is there an opportunity to include a `bash` script (e.g. `cd name; git init;`in the `g8` template, so that it will be executed upon issuing `g8` command?